# Android : Childs of a relative layout either overlap each other or only the last or the first one is visible

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am using this code to get the contents from a source and hence using dynamic initialisation.

The problem is that the views made by the createcomment(), overlap each other.

What can be done so that overlapping does not occur??

**createdynamic**

```
    void createdymanic()
    {
        rl= new RelativeLayout(getActivity());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ivprofile = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textname = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textdate = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textbody = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imagelike = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imagecomment = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageshare = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editcomment = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



        // set picture of the person
        ivprofilepic= new ImageView(getActivity());
        ivprofile.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ivprofile.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        ivprofile.setMargins(5,5,0,0);
        ivprofilepic.setId(1);
        ivprofilepic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);



        tvname= new TextView(getActivity());
        textname.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        textname.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, ivprofilepic.getId());
        textname.setMargins(8, 5, 0, 0);
        tvname.setId(2);
        tvname.setText("Name");
        tvname.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor));
        tvname.setTextSize(18);

        tvdate= new TextView(getActivity());
        textdate.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, ivprofilepic.getId());
        textdate.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, tvname.getId());
        textdate.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvname.getId());
        tvdate.setId(3);
        tvname.setText("Date");


        tvcontent= new TextView(getActivity());
        textbody.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        textbody.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ivprofilepic.getId());
        textbody.setMargins(5,0,0,0);
        tvcontent.setId(4);
        tvcontent.setText("Content");


        iblike= new Button(getActivity());

        imagelike.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        imagelike.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvcontent.getId());
        imagelike.setMargins(5, 7, 0, 0);
        iblike.setId(5);
        iblike.setText("like");


        ibcomment= new Button(getActivity());
        imagecomment.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, iblike.getId());
        imagecomment.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        ibcomment.setId(6);
        ibcomment.setText("comment");


        ibshare= new Button(getActivity());
        imageshare.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        imageshare.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, iblike.getId());
        imageshare.setMargins(0,0,0,5);
        ibshare.setId(7);
        ibshare.setText("share");

        etcommentbody= new EditText(getActivity());
        editcomment.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        editcomment.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, iblike.getId());
        editcomment.setMargins(5,8,0,0);
        etcommentbody.setId(8);
        etcommentbody.setHint("Add a comment...");

        rl.addView(ivprofilepic, ivprofile);
        rl.addView(tvname, textname);
        rl.addView(tvdate ,textdate);
        rl.addView(tvcontent, textbody);
        rl.addView(iblike, imagelike);
        rl.addView(ibcomment, imagecomment);
        rl.addView(ibshare, imageshare);
        rl.addView(etcommentbody, editcomment);

        mainlayout.addView(rl, 0, rlp);

        tvname.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //profile pe le jaana h yaha se
                //profile class banegi
            }
        });

        iblike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Caller().execute("3", api, id);
            }
        });

        ibcomment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String a=etcommentbody.getText().toString();
                new Caller().execute("4", api, id,a);
            }
        });

        ibshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              h.share(user_id, post_id);
            }
        });
    }
```

**createcomments**

```
    void createcomment()
    {
        RelativeLayout clayout= new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams clp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //clp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, etcommentbody.getId());
        clp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ivcommentprofile = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textcommentname = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textcommentdate = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textcommentbody = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        ivcommentprofilepic= new ImageView(getActivity());
        ivcommentprofile.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ivcommentprofile.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        ivcommentprofile.setMargins(5,5,0,0);
        ivcommentprofilepic.setId(101);
        ivcommentprofilepic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);




        tvcommentname= new TextView(getActivity());
        textcommentname.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        textcommentname.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, ivcommentprofilepic.getId());
        textcommentname.setMargins(5,5,0,0);
        tvcommentname.setId(102);
        tvcommentname.setText("Name");
        tvcommentname.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor));
        tvcommentname.setTextSize(18);

        tvcommentdate= new TextView(getActivity());
        textcommentdate.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, ivcommentprofilepic.getId());
        textcommentdate.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, ivcommentprofilepic.getId());
        textcommentdate.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvcommentname.getId());
        textcommentdate.setMargins(5, 3, 0, 0);
        tvcommentdate.setId(3);
        tvcommentdate.setText("Date");


        tvcommentcontent= new TextView(getActivity());
        textcommentbody.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        textcommentbody.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ivcommentprofilepic.getId());
        textcommentbody.setMargins(5,0,0,0);
        tvcommentcontent.setId(4);
        tvcommentcontent.setText("Content");



        clayout.addView(ivcommentprofilepic, ivcommentprofile);
        clayout.addView(tvcommentname, textcommentname);
        clayout.addView(tvcommentdate ,textcommentdate);
        clayout.addView(tvcommentcontent, textcommentbody);
        rl.addView(clayout, clp);

    }
```

I use the following statements

```
for(ka=0;ka<jsarray.length();ka++){
    createdymanic(ka);

    // setting on click listener and all

    for(int i=0;i<comment_array.length();i++){
    createcomment(i);

        // detting onclicklistener and all
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for creating such a lame question.

The problem was that the default value of commentlayout's orientation is horizontal by default.

The following code solved the problem :

```
commentlayout= new LinearLayout(getActivity());
commentlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your last text view you're adding (tvcommentcontent) doesn't have a right bound, so your third (tvcommentdate) and your 4th view (tvcommentcontent) you're adding are overlapping. Try adding

```
textcommentbody.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, tvcommentdate.getId());
```

right above your

```
textcommentbody.setMargins(5,0,0,0);
```

line.  This should make sure the last view stayes on the left of the third view. (I made a sweet diagram with MS paint to show this better but apparently new users can't add images :) )

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. The clayout is added according to me in my code but only one of them is displayed (the last one).